# Quantity of last item updated in whole database in php

Tags: php, mysql, cart, shopping-cart

I'm doing my semester project of e commerce website using php and MySQL. I built a cart system using both tools. The problem arose for me is that when the cart contain only one item it will work as intended i.e update the reflected quantity in database "quantity" column. But as I increase the items in my cart it will not work as I thought i.e. it only update the whole database quantity column with the last item quantity.
Below is my code.
Any help would be very helpful as right now I'm learning this stuff.

**Welcome Guest!**
                    Shopping Cart
                    - Items:  - Price:  - 
                    Go to Cart

```
            <div id="products_box"><!-- gets the products from the database section starts from here -->
                <form action="cart.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table width="750px" align="center" bgcolor="#0099CC">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td><b>Remove</b></td>
                            <td><b>Product(s)</b></td>
                            <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                            <td><b>Total Price</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $ip_add = getIp();
                        $total = 0;

                        $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add = '$ip_add'";
                        $run_price = mysqli_query($db, $sel_price);

                        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){
                            $product_id = $record['product_id'];

                            $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id = '$product_id'";
                            $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($con, $pro_price);

                            while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){

                                $product_price = array($p_price['product_price']);
                                $product_title = $p_price['product_title'];
                                $product_img = $p_price['product_img2'];
                                $single_price = $p_price['product_price'];

                                $value = array_sum($product_price);
                                $total += $value;


                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $product_id;?>"></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product_title;?><br><img src="admin_area/products_images/<?php echo $product_img;?>" width="80px" height="80px"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="3" min="1"></td>
                            <?php 
                                if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                                    $qty = $_POST['qty'];


                                    $insert_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' where ip_add='$ip_add' AND product_id = '$product_id'";

                                    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $insert_qty);


                                    $total *= $qty;
                                }
                            ?>
                            <td><?php echo  $single_price ." ". "&euro;"?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            } // to include in the php code so it effects the whole row
                        }?> 
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Sub Total:</b></td>
                            <td><b><?php echo $total ." ". "&euro;"?></b></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Cart"></td>

                            <td> <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping"></td>
                            <td><button><a href="checkout.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">Checkout</a></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

Comment: Your code is a little messy, in that you have the select query running a loop and then another select query running another loop, and within it you output the form and then try to update. Your code might be fixable as is (I can't see the issue from a quick look). However, I strongly suggest separating these things out a bit. Check at the top if they have pressed "update", if so the form should POST an array,  loop that POST array and update each item in the DB. Then loop to get all product data and set it into a new array. Then use that array to output the data in your cart.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a HTML form, if it contains multiple form elements with the same name, only the last one is sent. Since all your quantity input boxes have the name `qty`, only the quantity of the last product in the cart gets submitted, so that's why all your products end up with that number.

PHP has a feature which allows you to use square brackets in form element names and end up with an array of data instead (see the section on http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php for more info about how this works). You can either use `[]` to have the value appended to the array (which you are already doing for your "remove item from cart" checkbox), or you can give it a specific array key by naming the element something like `qty[foo]` (which would end up in `$_POST['qty']['foo']`).

There are a few different ways you could fix this. Since this is a project, I'm just going to point you towards one possible solution and suggest changing your quantity form element to:

```
<input type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $product_id;?>">]" value="1" size="3" min="1">
```

then see what the `$_POST` data looks like.

You will also need to modify your update quantities code to ensure you are using the quantity for appropriate product.

Other comments:

An IP address is not unique to a user, so this is not a good way to uniquely identify a cart (you may already know this). At the moment, users with the same IP address will all share the same shopping cart.

Your `$total` calculation looks a bit suspect (try adding multiple items to your cart with different quantities).

Your script also appears vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider what your SQL query would look like if a malicious user typed the string `1', product_id='123', ip_add='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` into the quantity box - this would allow them to easily add any product to any other user's cart.